# GPS functionality degradation on Galaxy SIII

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s-3, gps

I recently moved from a relatively flat area to an area near the mountains. I used to have good reception for my GPS when I would run using the RunKeeper app. Now I only get reception for about half of my run. The App shows 'green' on the reception meeter, and I can use Navigation and other GPS driven apps without a problem. Is there anything I can do to test the GPS functionality within the given area? Is there any known reasons why an app would not properly work even though it says it is getting sufficient reception?

Answer (score 1):

I had big problems with GPS in my galaxy s2, the connection was unstable and sometimes it took 30 minuts to get the signal

To analyze the GPS signal you can use something like GPS status

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2

I've discovered that my phone was suddenly loosing all the signals, so I suspected an hardware problem

The GPS uses as antenna the metallic board that is inside the phone

I've disassembled the phone, and Cleaned this board from oxidation in correspondence of every screw with a nail file

I'm surprised of the result the GPS signal really busted (it fix in 30 seconds inside the house) and is totally stable

You can find here a video tutorial specific for s3

Galaxy S3 Gps Fix (When Screw Tightening Doesn't …: http://youtu.be/VI4hs19riRM